# Custom user description

Tags: feature-request

I suggest to add a feature by which I can add a note for any nickname, so that every time I see them, I see those notes as I hover my mouse over their nickname.

### Suggested work-flow:

- I interact with some person (he helps me, I help him, we discuss in chat something, etc).
- Based on such interaction, I write some comments about this person.
- These comments are local to me. No one can see them.
- I use these comments so that next time I can adjust my actions towards him most optimally.

### Motivation:

Such notes will enable me to better identify the person that I am interacting or about to interact with. This knowledge about such person will ultimately allow me to hypothesize a more optimal interaction approach than simply following the null hypothesis (latter is less optimal on average than the former).

Comment: We very much work to ensure our sites are not social networks - this seems to drive them in the opposite direction.

Comment: Most popular note: "This user is an a**, downvote on sight."

Comment: @Oded, if that's the case, then how about randomize nicknames per question session?

Comment: It is somewhat unclear about what actions you're talking but most, if not all, actions should be based on the merit of the post, not on the user.

Comment: @rene, should the nicknames get automatically ranomized for each question?

Comment: I don't see a reason for that. If you have arguments why that should be done and what bad behavior will be mitigated with that, please state them. IIRC it was considered in the early stages of SO development to have no usercards at all in the posts. Maybe the podcasts have a deeper dicussion on why that wasn't done in the end.

Comment: @rene, if you were right that actions to be only based on the merit of the post independent of the person behind it, then user ids better be randomized (with user cards hidden).

Comment: You have to provide evidence then where voting, editing or commenting is done solely based on the user and not on the post and why you think it is bad if this continues. The trade-off probably is that users don't want to post if their contribution isn't visible. So you might have fixed one small issue but you've created a new big issue.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a social site in which we determine the "status" of our fellow members. A lot of times, this becomes a problem like how animuson said:

> Most popular note: "This user is an a**, downvote on sight."

Or maybe the complete opposite, but this feature kinda makes SE more of a Q/A site with dislikes and likes for users. This is unnecessary and cause multiple tensions and online fights we do not need here at all. You can't really have a good idea on how to interact - they're just another user like you and me with opinions and different views on stuff.

Actions and posts and etc. should depend on the post, not the user. For example, if Jon Skeet's best post was made by another user, I don't care! The post is what matters, not the user. If you want to rant about the user, try going to Facebook and ranting appropriately but not here. We want questions and answers of high-quality answers with appropriately made actions from ***unbiased users***.

Comment: Do you think that ranomizing the nicknames per each question session is better? Because by randomizing that per question session, people get even less biased.

Comment: We need users that aren't biased at all

Comment: And how would like to achieve this objective? (i.e. more users that arent biased at all)